# Playframework infinite timeout for web-service call

Tags: scala, playframework

How to set an infinite timeout when making play WS call and wait until the response is received?

Comment: Wrap your call in a Future. Awaiting infinitely for the result of a call is a bad idea in a running application, in case it never resolves or falls over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting infinitely is a bad idea. However, if you still want to proceed with this approach, you can use

```
val resp = ws.url("myurl").withRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf).get()
```

Comment: @rkc Please let me know if this answers your question.